# How to maintain same chat history in multiple tab of same browser while using web chat in python?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, botframework

Bot Info
SDK Platform: python
SDK Version:
Active Channels: Web chat
Deployment Environment: Azure Bot Service

Issue Description
I am using web chat channel to show chatting window in my website. It clears chat history and starts chat from beginning when I refresh page or open new page in new browser tab. How can I maintain same chat history between multiple tabs or when I refresh the page?

Comment: This should get you started. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60085336/7095607

Comment: @vireshkore - Did you have a look at the question Hessel linked you to? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @vireshkore - Are you still working on this?